# What is a common C/C++ macro to determine the size of a structure member?

Tags: c++, sizeof

In C/C++, how do I determine the size of the member variable to a structure without needing to define a dummy variable of that structure type? Here's an example of how to do it wrong, but shows the intent:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
  int x[10];
  int y;
} myStruct_t;

const size_t sizeof_MyStruct_x = sizeof(myStruct_t.x);  // error
```

For reference, this should be how to find the size of 'x' if you first define a dummy variable:

```
myStruct_t dummyStructVar;

const size_t sizeof_MyStruct_x = sizeof(dummyStructVar.x);
```

However, I'm hoping to avoid having to create a dummy variable just to get the size of 'x'. I think there's a clever way to recast 0 as a myStruct_t to help find the size of member variable 'x', but it's been long enough that I've forgotten the details, and can't seem to get a good Google search on this.  Do you know?

Thanks!

Comment: If you land on this page but are looking for this instead, here you go: [How can I print the result of `sizeof()` at compile time in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20979565/4561887).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In C++ (which is what the tags say), your "dummy variable" code can be replaced with:

```
sizeof myStruct_t().x;
```

No  myStruct_t object will be created: the compiler only works out the static type of sizeof's operand, it doesn't execute the expression.

This works in C, and in C++ is better because it also works for classes without an accessible no-args constructor:

```
sizeof ((myStruct_t *)0)->x
```

Comment: Cool!  This worked for me in C++.  Is there also a way to do it in C?

Comment: and what about C? I don't need this but i'd really like to know :-)

Comment: The first approach will, obviously, only work for struct with an accessible default constructor (implicit or explitit). The second one is universal, and works in C and C++ alike.

Comment: By the way, sizeof( myStruct_t::x ) will work in c++0x (source wikipedia)

Comment: @Pavel: good point, my first snippet really was just making the "dummy variable" code work without executing the constructor. @Lucas, well the question did ask for a macro, so I don't blame those who provided one. But the questioner sounded smart enough to me to handle that part.

Answer (score 11):

I'm using following macro:

```
#include <iostream>
#define DIM_FIELD(struct_type, field) (sizeof( ((struct_type*)0)->field ))
int main()
{
    struct ABC
    {
        int a;
        char b;
        double c;
    };
    std::cout << "ABC::a=" << DIM_FIELD(ABC, a) 
              << " ABC::c=" << DIM_FIELD(ABC, c) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Trick is treating 0 as pointer to your struct. This is resolved at compile time so it safe.

Comment: Good!  That was the macro I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do

```
sizeof(myStruct().x)
```

As sizeof parameter is never executed, you'll not really create that object.

Answer (score 3):

Any of these should work:

```
sizeof(myStruct_t().x;);
```

or

```
myStruct_t *tempPtr = NULL;
sizeof(tempPtr->x)
```

or

```
sizeof(((myStruct_t *)NULL)->x);
```

Because `sizeof` is evaluated at compile-time, not run-time, you won't have a problem dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that only works for `myStruct_t` and `myStruct` but not for `struct myStruct` :/

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, this can be done with `sizeof(myStruct_t::x)`. C++11 also adds [std::declval](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval), which can be used for this (among other things):

```
#include <utility>
typedef struct myStruct {
  int x[10];
  int y;
} myStruct_t;

const std::size_t sizeof_MyStruct_x_normal = sizeof(myStruct_t::x);
const std::size_t sizeof_MyStruct_x_declval = sizeof(std::declval<myStruct_t>().x);
```

Answer (score 0):

From my utility macros header:

```
#define FIELD_SIZE(type, field) (sizeof(((type *)0)->field))
```

invoked like so:

```
FIELD_SIZE(myStruct_t, x);
```