# Is calling a function on a NULL pointer undefined?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When does invoking a member function on a null instance result in undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha)
>   [C++ standard: dereferencing NULL pointer to get a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727834/c-standard-dereferencing-null-pointer-to-get-a-reference)

Say I have the class:

```
class A
{
public:
   void foo() { cout << "foo"; }
};
```

and call foo like so:

```
A* a = NULL;
a->foo();
```

I suspect this invokes undefined behavior, since it's equivalent to `(*a).foo()` (or is it?), and dereferencing a `NULL` **is** UB, but I can't find the reference. Can anyone help me out? Or is it defined?

No, the function is not `virtual`. No, I'm not accessing any members.

EDIT: I voted to close this question but will not delete it as I couldn't find the duplicate myself, and I suspect this title might be easier to find by others.

Comment: I don't think there's anything in the standard that restricts, for example, implementing *all* member functions via vtable lookup.  So in such an implementation, you really would be dereferencing NULL (rather than just statically binding to `a::foo`).  I can't provide a standard quote, though.

Comment: So the question is: "What is the reference saying you can't dereference a NULL pointer?"

Comment: THis post has a detailed analysis of the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669742/accessing-class-members-on-a-null-pointer

Comment: @MooingDuck no. I'm looking for the reference that says `a->x` is equivalent to `(*a).x`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248877/accessing-static-member-through-invalid-pointer-guaranteed-to-work

Comment: @Joe That's what I said. I'm looking for the standard quote that says the part about the "syntactic sugar".

Comment: This previously answered question may help a lot:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669742/accessing-class-members-on-a-null-pointer

Comment: An extensive discussion of this topic is given [in this post][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha

Comment: @Scott: Please join me in dup-voting.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yeah figured, look at the update on my answer, includes a link to a good post with a discussion on this topic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm looking for the reference that says `a->x` is equivalent to `(*a).x`.

Here it is:

> `[C++11: 5.2.5/2]:` For the first option (dot) the first expression shall have complete class type. For the second option (arrow) the first expression shall have pointer to complete class type. **The expression `E1->E2` is converted to the equivalent form `(*(E1)).E2`;** the remainder of 5.2.5 will address only the first option (dot). In either case, the *id-expression* shall name a member of the class or of one of its base classes. [ *Note:* because the name of a class is inserted in its class scope (Clause 9), the name of a class is also considered a nested member of that class. *—end note* ] [ *Note:* 3.4.5 describes how names are looked up after the `.` and `->` operators. *—end note* ]

There is no direct quotation for dereferencing a NULL pointer being UB, unfortunately. You may find more under this question: [When does invoking a member function on a null instance result in undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha)

Comment: 8.3.2/4 "References"): Note: in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by dereferencing a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727834/c-standard-dereferencing-null-pointer-to-get-a-reference

Comment: @0A0D: That's non-normative. GMan explores the topic in more detail in the post I linked to, including quoting that same non-normative passage that you posted in your comment, but going further with some balanced reasoning. I suggest reading it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of at least one case where this idiom is not only allowed but relied upon: Microsoft's MFC class CWnd provides a member function GetSafeHwnd which tests if `this==NULL` and returns without accessing any member variables.

Of course there are plenty of people who would claim that MFC is a very bad example.

Regardless of whether the behavior is undefined or not, in practice it's not likely to behave badly. The compiler will treat `a->foo()` as `A::foo(a)` which does not do a dereference at the call site, as long as `foo` is not virtual.

Comment: That's the exact reason I'm asking. I saw this in production code, I'm assuming it's UB, but I also want to prove it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, it's a good question. The implementation of `GetSafeHwnd` has always made me a little nervous, even though I understand why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is UB as `a` has not been initialized to point to a valid memory location before it is dereferenced.

Comment: I'm looking for a quote from the standard. Your answer provides no additional information than I already stated in the question. PS I did not downvote.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Well it's pretty common knowledge that this is UB, but the standard isn't free and I don't have it lying around.

Comment: There are some free drafts lying around, not much different than the official version.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Ok, I should grab one.  I forget that the drafts are actually free.

Answer (score 0):

It is covered here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232

> At least a couple of places in the IS state that indirection through a
>   null pointer produces undefined behavior: 1.9 [intro.execution]
>   paragraph 4 gives "dereferencing the null pointer" as an example of
>   undefined behavior, and 8.3.2 [dcl.ref] paragraph 4 (in a note) uses
>   this supposedly undefined behavior as justification for the
>   nonexistence of "null references."
>
> However, 5.3.1 [expr.unary.op] paragraph 1, which describes the unary
>   "*" operator, does not say that the behavior is undefined if the
>   operand is a null pointer, as one might expect. Furthermore, at least
>   one passage gives dereferencing a null pointer well-defined behavior:
>   5.2.8 [expr.typeid] paragraph 2 says
>
> If the lvalue expression is obtained by applying the unary * operator
>   to a pointer and the pointer is a null pointer value (4.10
>   [conv.ptr]), the typeid expression throws the bad_typeid exception
>   (18.7.3 [bad.typeid]).
>
> This is inconsistent and should be cleaned up.

Read more at the link if you want to learn more.

Comment: This is a good quote and very pertinent. However, that hardly "covers" it; it merely agrees that this is a question to be answered; it does not answer it in itself.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm not going to plagiarize the whole page.

Comment: If you did it wouldn't change anything. Open issues are not specifications.