# Count lines between two code locations in C preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to use the C preprocessor to count the amount of lines between two code locations. The basic idea is something like this:

```
#define START __LINE__
static char* string_list[] = {
    "some string",
    "another string",
    ...
    "last string"
};
#define END __LINE__
#if END - START > 42
    #error Too many entries
#endif
```

Of course this doesn't work because in this case `START` and `END` are merely redefinitions of the `__LINE__` macro.
I was playing around a bit with the `#` and `##` operators, but I could not get the preprocessor to evaluate `START` and `END` while the preprocessor is running.

My question is: is this possible at all?

Checking the size of the array during runtime is not an option.
Thanks for any hints or ideas in advance!

Comment: Advise `static const char* string_list[]...`

Comment: “Checking the size of the array during runtime”—that's impossible in C. Are you aware that `sizeof` yields a compile-time constant? And is “while the preprocessor is running” really a requirement (what `sizeof` wouldn't fulfill)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't use those macros for that purpose: the code will become completely unmaintainable if you introduce an extra line somewhere. And what if there are too few lines?

Instead of macros, use a static assert:

```
static_assert(sizeof(string_list) / sizeof(*string_list) == SOME_CONSTANT,
               "Wrong number of entries in string list.");
```

If you aren't using C11 which has support for static_assert, you can write such an assert yourself, for example like this:

```
#define COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(expr) {typedef uint8_t COMP_TIME_ASSERT[(expr) ? 1 : 0];}
```

Comment: +1. That COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT macro is cuter than the one I've been using for the last googleplex years.

Comment: @Bathsheba There's certainly a lot of such ugly macros out there :) Personally I think the standardized `static_assert` is reason enough for upgrading to C11.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems like a reasonable way of accomplishing what I want

Comment: I would suggest to have the array be of size -1 instead of 0 to make the assertion fail. Just tested with GCC 4.9.0 only with -std=c99 and no other special switches specified and the code compiles fine with above macro as is. Array size of 0 only breaks if -pedantic is set. Array size of -1 does break with or without the switch so it makes it more reliable.

Comment: @PuerNoctis Test with a compliant C compiler instead. GCC is not a compliant C compiler unless you compile with `std=c99 -pedantic-errors`. GCC has a non-standard extension that allows arrays with size zero. This is not allowed by the C standard. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c/9723093#9723093)

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the clarification, I assumed that GCC is C-compliant by default (which is wrong, obviously). But proof-of-concept aside, wouldn't -1 still be more reliable to cover more scenarios, e.g. in exactly this case where someone does NOT use a C-compliant compiler that allow zero sized arrays?

Comment: @PuerNoctis The C standard clearly states black on white that it must be a number greater than zero, so -1 makes no difference. The solution is to switch to a compliant compiler instead. Luckily in the case of GCC, this is easy to do by adding two compiler options.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this and wondering, here are more static assert options: [Static assert in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3385515/4561887), including [my comprehensive answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54993033/4561887).

Answer (score 8):

[Acknowledge [@Lundin who points out that you can use a `typedef`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551721/count-lines-between-two-code-locations-in-c-preprocessor/24551805#comment38024001_24551912)]

This is one way

```
typedef uint8_t START[__LINE__]; /*put this on one line*/

typedef uint8_t END[__LINE__]; /*put this on another line*/
```

`sizeof(END) - sizeof(START)` is a **compile-time** expression giving the line offset.

Put in macros and rename `START` and `END` to taste.

Comment: Or use `typedef uint8_t n1[__LINE__];` so that you don't have to actually allocate anything. Still, this doesn't solve the core problem, which is that `__LINE__` macros are unsuitable for static checking of array sizes.

Comment: @Lundin: that's elegant and works for me (gcc and msvc2012). I've amended.

Comment: @Lundin, you mentioned "the core problem, which is that `__LINE__` macros are unsuitable for static checking of array sizes." Enums are suitable for checking array, variable, and type sizes at compile-time. I'll post an elegant enum-based answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20979565/4561887) next week, where I can call this: `COMPILE_TIME_PRINT_SIZEOF(My_struct);` to get this compile-time output, showing the `My_struct` size as `24` bytes: `error: case value ‘24’ not in enumerated type ‘enum This_is_the_size_of_your_type_e’ [-Werror=switch]`.

Comment: @Lundin, here it is. Just added it: [Printing the size of (`sizeof()`) a type or variable in an error message at compile time in both C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78144837/4561887)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the array thus:

```
static const char* string_list[42] = {...
```

The compiler will tell you if you provide too many initialisers.  You can provide a sentinel entry to mark the end if necessary:

```
static char* string_list[43] = { ..., NULL } ;
```

And perhaps write a function to determine the length at runtime if you need to know that.

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't protect you against too few initializers.

Comment: Of course not, but the code in the question was never testing for *too few*.