# Is there a way to get the value of __LINE__ on one line and use that value on other lines?

Tags: c-preprocessor

Essentially, I want to do this:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
static const unsigned line_after_includes = __LINE__;

int main()
{
    foo(line_after_includes);
    bar(line_after_includes);
    return 0;
}
```

Except like this:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
#define LINE_AFTER_INCLUDES __LINE__

int main()
{
    FOO(LINE_AFTER_INCLUDES);
    BAR(LINE_AFTER_INCLUDES);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to make `LINE_AFTER_INCLUDES` expand to the value of `__LINE__` on the line on which `LINE_AFTER_INCLUDES` was defined, so I can use it with other macros later? I would just use a variable like in the first code snippet, but I need the value as an integer literal, because I will be using it in a switch statement. The alternative is to do

```
    #define LINE_AFTER_INCLUDES 3 // MAKE SURE THIS IS ON LINE IT'S DEFINED AS!!!
```

which is ugly and harder to maintain. I would settle for that, but I will be doing something a bit more complex than this example...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do this is given in @Bathsheba's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24551912/1366431

```
typedef char LINE_AFTER_INCLUDES[__LINE__];
```

You can then access the value of `__LINE__` at that declaration by calling `sizeof(LINE_AFTER_INCLUDES)`, because its value has been fixed into part of the newly-declared array type. `sizeof` is a C-level compile-time constant, which works for `switch` and related things (no division is necessary: the size of `char` is guaranteed to be 1, as it's the unit of measurement). The only disadvantage of this is that it's C-level rather than preprocessor-level, so it can't be used with `#if` or for token-pasting.

---

(original, which I spent ages typing:)

So the problem here is that macro definitions are lazy; i.e. that macro invocations aren't expanded until they're actually needed to be inserted into some kind of output. Because of this, `__LINE__`'s expansion is delayed until it's too late.

Luckily, there's a way to force eager evaluation in the preprocessor - the macro only needs to be demanded by *some kind* of output - not necessarily program body text. Remember that macros can also be expanded to form the arguments to preprocessor directives - and that preprocessor directives are then - having been controlled by the forced expansion - able to create further definitions. This handy observation is the basis of Boost's ["evaluated slots" functionality](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/evaluated_slots.html), which uses it to provide things like eager evaluation and mutable preprocessor variable slots.

Unfortunately you can't use Boost slots with `__LINE__`, as it suffers from the same problem - but we can steal the idea to produce two rather inelegant solutions. They're each ugly in their own special ways.

#### Option 1:

Use a shell script to produce a large number (a few hundred?) of `include`-able files with the following naming scheme and contents:

```
// linedefs/_42_.h
#define LINE_AFTER_INCLUDES 42
```

...then use as follows:

```
#define GEN_LINE_INC(L) _GEN_LINE_S(_GEN_LINE_(L))
#define _GEN_LINE_(L) linedefs/_##L##_.h
#define _GEN_LINE_S(S) _GEN_LINE_S2(S)
#define _GEN_LINE_S2(S) #S

#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

#include GEN_LINE_INC(__LINE__)

int main()
{
    FOO(LINE_AFTER_INCLUDES);
    BAR(LINE_AFTER_INCLUDES);
    return 0;
}
```

In other words, use the `#include` directive to force expansion of a macro which converts `__LINE__` into a filename; including that filename produces the right value for the constant. This is inelegant because it requires a load of extra files and an external tool to generate them, but it's very simple.

#### Option 2:

Insert a large and ugly block into your main file below the `#include` section:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

// <- This line is the one we generate the number for
#define LINE_BIT_0 0
#define LINE_BIT_1 0
#define LINE_BIT_2 0
#define LINE_BIT_3 0
#define LINE_BIT_4 0
#define LINE_BIT_5 0
#if (__LINE__ - 7) & 1
#  undef LINE_BIT_0
#  define LINE_BIT_0 1
#endif
#if (__LINE__ - 11) >> 1 & 1
#  undef LINE_BIT_1
#  define LINE_BIT_1 (1 << 1)
#endif
#if (__LINE__ - 15) >> 2 & 1
#  undef LINE_BIT_2
#  define LINE_BIT_2 (1 << 2)
#endif
#if (__LINE__ - 19) >> 3 & 1
#  undef LINE_BIT_3
#  define LINE_BIT_3 (1 << 3)
#endif
#if (__LINE__ - 23) >> 4 & 1
#  undef LINE_BIT_4
#  define LINE_BIT_4 (1 << 4)
#endif
#if (__LINE__ - 27) >> 5 & 1
#  undef LINE_BIT_5
#  define LINE_BIT_5 (1 << 5)
#endif
#define LINE_AFTER_INCLUDES (LINE_BIT_0 | LINE_BIT_1 | LINE_BIT_2 | LINE_BIT_3 | LINE_BIT_4 | LINE_BIT_5)


int main() ...
```

This version uses the `#if` directive to force expansion of the `__LINE__` macro and convert it into bitflags, which are then recombined at the end. This is *highly* inelegant because it relies on precomputing the distance between each `#if` and the top of the block, since `__LINE__` evaluates to different values in the course of the block; and it *can't be factored out* and hidden in a separate file, or else `__LINE__` wouldn't work. Still, it works, and it doesn't require an external tool.

(In the event you have a huge number of `#include` lines, extending it to more than 6 bits should be straightforward.)

On the other hand, this sounds like an X/Y problem to me. There has to be an alternative to `__LINE__` that would work better for this. If you're counting the number of `#include`d files, perhaps you could use something like a line incrementing Boost.Counter at the end of each one? That way, you also wouldn't be vulnerable to formatting changes (e.g. blank lines in the `#include` section).

Comment: "this sounds like an X/Y problem to me" As I hinted at the end of the question, counting includes is just a minimal example. I'm actually trying to implement coroutines as syntax sugar using macros (just for fun - no one else will have to maintain this).

Comment: Shouldn't there be double quotes in `_GEN_LINE_`?

Comment: Awesome. Playing with macros is its own reward! And no, the output of `_GEN_LINE_` is passed to `_GEN_LINE_S` to be stringified there. (What I can't guarantee, off the top of my head, is whether this will *definitely* not insert spaces between e.g. the `_` and the `.`. But it works with GCC.)

Comment: By complete chance, there's also a *far* superior method here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24551912/1366431 - please, use that.

Comment: You should add that to the beginning of your answer, but the other options are still useful if someone wants to use the value in an `#if`, since the preprocessor can't evaluate `sizeof`.