# Difference between #pragma and _Pragma() in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

What is the difference between `#pragma` and `_Pragma()` in C?

syntax:

```
#pragma arg
```

and

```
_Pragma(arg)
```

When should I use `_Pragma(arg)`?

Comment: The C standard provides the `_Pragma` operator as an alternative to `#pragma`.  It's likely that `_pragma` is similar but specific to a vendor (Microsoft?).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`_Pragma` operator introduced in `C99`. `_Pragma(arg)` is an operator, much like `sizeof` or `defined`, and can be embedded in a macro.

According to [cpp.gnu.org](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html) reference:

> Its syntax is `_Pragma (string-literal)`, where *string-literal* can be either a normal or wide-character string literal. **It is destringized, by replacing all `\\` with a single `\` and all `\"` with a `"`.** The result is then processed as if it had appeared as the right hand side of a `#pragma` directive. For example,
>
> ```
>  _Pragma ("GCC dependency \"parse.y\"")
> ```
>
> has the same effect as `#pragma GCC dependency "parse.y"`.
> The same effect could be achieved using macros, for example
>
> ```
>  #define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma (#x)
>  DO_PRAGMA (GCC dependency "parse.y")
> ```

According to [IBM tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.cbclx01/c99preprocessor.htm):

> **The _Pragma operator is an alternative method of specifying #pragma
> directives.** For example, the following two statements are equivalent:
>
> ```
> #pragma comment(copyright, "IBM 2010")
> _Pragma("comment(copyright, \"IBM 2010\")")
> ```
>
> The string IBM 2010 is inserted into the C++ object file when the
> following code is compiled:
>
> ```
> _Pragma("comment(copyright, \"IBM 2010\")")
> int main() 
> {
>    return 0;
> }
> ```

For more information about [_pragma](http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/cinanutshell/0596006977/cinanut-CHP-14-SECT-7.html) with example.

Answer (score 11):

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx):

> Pragma directives specify machine- or operating-specific compiler features. **The __pragma keyword, which is specific to the Microsoft compiler**, enables you to code pragma directives within macro definitions.

Also (same link):

> The __pragma() Keyword
>
> Microsoft specific
>
> The compiler also supports the `__pragma` keyword, which has the same functionality as the `#pragma` directive, but can be used inline in a macro definition. The `#pragma` directive cannot be used in a macro definition because the compiler interprets the number sign character ('#') in the directive to be the stringizing operator (#).

So basically you can always use `#pragma` instead of `__pragma()`. There is no need to use `__pragma()`, but it *can* be used sometimes.

Comment: After edits, the OP mentions `_Pragma` which is standard C as per C99. See C17 6.10.9. Unlike `__pragma` which might very well be some MS goo. You might want to update this answer since it doesn't address the syntax used in the question. The original question had `_pragma` which is neither ISO C nor (as far as I know) MS goo.