# Portable loop unrolling with template parameter in C++ with GCC/ICC

Tags: c++, gcc, hpc, icc, loop-unrolling

I am working on a [high-performance parallel computational fluid dynamics code](https://github.com/2b-t/LB-t) that involves a lot of lightweight loops and therefore gains approximately 30% in performance if all important loops are fully unrolled.

This can be done easily for a fixed number of loops by using **compiler directives**: [`#pragma GCC unroll (16)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Loop-Specific-Pragmas.html) is recognized by both compilers I am aiming for, the Intel C++ compiler ICC and GCC, while [`#pragma unroll (16)`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.cbclx01/opt_unroll.htm) is sadly ignored by GCC. I can also use **template parameters or pre-preprocessor directives as as limits** with ICC ([similar to what you can do with nvcc](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/new-compiler-features-cuda-8/)), for instance

```
template <int N>
// ...
#pragma unroll (N)
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
// ...
}
```

or

```
#define N 16

#pragma unroll (N)
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
// ...
}
```

throw no error or warning with `-Wall -w2 -w3` when compiling with ICC while the complementary syntax `#pragma GCC unroll (N)` with GCC (`-Wall -pedantic`) throws an error in GCC 9.2.1 20191102 in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
error: ‘#pragma GCC unroll’ requires an assignment-expression that evaluates to a non-negative integral constant less than 65535
#pragma GCC unroll (N)
```

Is somebody aware of a way to make **loop unrolling based on a template parameter with compiler directives work in a portable way** (at least working with GCC and ICC)? I actually only need **full unrolling** of the entire loop, so something like `#pragma GCC unroll (all)` would already help me a lot.

I am aware that there exist more or less complex strategies to [unroll loops with template meta-programming](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30667&seqNum=7) but as in my application the loops might be nested and can contain more complicated loop bodies, I feel like such a strategy would over-complicate my code and reduce readibility.

Comment: The idiomatic GCC approach for full unrolling of a given loop would, afaik, unfortunately be a push/pop options approach, `#pragma GCC push_options`, `#pragma GCC optimize ("unroll-loops")`, `for ... `, `#pragma GCC pop_options`, which would not be portable with ICC, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly currently there does not seem to be a consistent way to do so.

I ended up using a **pre-processor macro** in combination with [**`_Pragma(string-literal)`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45477830/9938686) and a [**stringification macro**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791845/9938686) (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3030285/9938686)) that decides whether to unroll depending on the template parameter if the Intel C++ Compiler ICC or Clang is available, to use a constant factor for unrolling for GCC and ignore it for any other compiler. Here a small example:

```
/// Helper macros for stringification
#define TO_STRING_HELPER(X)   #X
#define TO_STRING(X)          TO_STRING_HELPER(X)

// Define loop unrolling depending on the compiler
#if defined(__ICC) || defined(__ICL)
  #define UNROLL_LOOP(n)      _Pragma(TO_STRING(unroll (n)))
#elif defined(__clang__)
  #define UNROLL_LOOP(n)      _Pragma(TO_STRING(unroll (n)))
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
  #define UNROLL_LOOP(n)      _Pragma(TO_STRING(GCC unroll (16)))
#elif defined(_MSC_BUILD)
  #pragma message ("Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC) detected: Loop unrolling not supported!")
  #define UNROLL_LOOP(n)
#else
  #warning "Unknown compiler: Loop unrolling not supported!"
  #define UNROLL_LOOP(n)
#endif

/// Example usage
template <int N>
void exampleContainingLoop() {
  UNROLL_LOOP(N)
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    // ...
  }
    
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use OpenMP (which is common in HPC): Since OpenMP 5.1, you can use the portable `#pragma omp unroll {full | partial [N]}`.