# Is it possible to output a variable from a header file?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Suppose I have a header file with lines like this:

```
#if LONG_BIT != 8 * SIZEOF_LONG
/* 04-Oct-2000 LONG_BIT is apparently (mis)defined as 64 on some recent
 * 32-bit platforms using gcc.  We try to catch that here at compile-time
 * rather than waiting for integer multiplication to trigger bogus
 * overflows.
 */
#error "pp897:  LONG_BIT  definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
#endif
```

I would like to output the value of LONG_BIT and SIZEOF_LONG.  Is it possible to do this, or is that impossible from a header file?

Comment: Same idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979565/how-can-i-print-the-result-of-sizeof-at-compile-time-in-c

Comment: No, they are not variables but instead they are constants. However, you can still output them with std::cout << LONG_BIT;

Comment: @Lehks Adding that just gives me:
/awips2/python/include/python2.7/pyport.h:900:1: error: ‘cout’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
 std::cout << LONG_BIT;
 ^

Comment: @EricPostpischil  So preprocessor macros can or cannot be output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few values to test in that case. You could test the plausible ones one by one like a switch/case statement, with a default just in case.

Standalone example. The 2 first `define` statements are here for the test, remove from final code

```
// completely bogus/incoherent values just to test
#define LONG_BIT 32
#define SIZEOF_LONG 4444

// operational test from now on    
#if LONG_BIT != 8 * SIZEOF_LONG
#if LONG_BIT == 32
#error "pp897:  LONG_BIT  definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?): size 32"
#elif LONG_BIT == 64
#error "pp897:  LONG_BIT  definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?): size 64"
#else
#error "pp897:  LONG_BIT  definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?): size ???"
#endif
#endif
```

compilation output:

```
test.c:7:2: error: #error "pp897:  LONG_BIT  definition appears wrong for platfo
rm (bad gcc/glibc config?): size 32"
```

This method is compatible with all standards including C89

Comment: It appears that by redefining a value, the compiler will say what it's value was:

warning: "SIZEOF_LONG" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define SIZEOF_LONG 4444
 ^
In file included from /acme/python/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from edex_HWR_sfc.C:44:
/acme/python/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1051:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define SIZEOF_LONG 8

Comment: of course, I did redefine it just to test as the comment states "// completely bogus value just to test"

Comment: Not sure why you reiterated that.  Nothing in my comment would seem to have prompted that.

Comment: ok, then if you want to redefine a value you have to `#undef` it first.

Comment: Thanks.  What I meant was, that by attempting to redefine it, the problem is solved -- the attempt causes gcc to display the value I was looking for in its warning!

Answer (score 4):

`_Static_assert` in C or `static_assert` in C++ can test conditions and display a string, and the string can be constructed with preprocessor expansions:

```
#define LONG_BIT    64
#define SIZEOF_LONG 4

#define StringizeHelper(x)  #x
#define Stringize(x)        StringizeHelper(x)

_Static_assert(LONG_BIT == 8 * SIZEOF_LONG,
    "LONG_BIT is " Stringize(LONG_BIT) " but must be 8 * "
    Stringize(SIZEOF_LONG) ".");
```

Output with Clang:

```
x.c:7:1: error: static_assert failed "LONG_BIT is 64 but must be 8 * 4."
_Static_assert(LONG_BIT == 8 * SIZEOF_LONG,
^              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Copied and pasted your code.  Using gcc I get:

/awips2/python/include/python2.7/pyport.h:897:15: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 _Static_assert(LONG_BIT == 8 * SIZEOF_LONG,

Comment: @Tharpa Are you compiling in [C](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lvJ21KxytEcEvDEO) or [C++](https://wandbox.org/permlink/N7FwO99MWX2E3Thw)?

Comment: @Bob__, looking at the Makefile, it has a line C++_FLAGS += -fexceptions, so I guess it's C++.

Answer (score 0):

With GCC or Clang (at least), you can print out the values of preprocessor macros:

```
#define LONG_BIT 60
#pragma message "LONG_BIT is " STRINGIFY(LONG_BIT)
```

But that won't get you the value of `sizeof(long)`, which is not a preprocessor construct. It also won't do arithmetic; `LONG_BIT` needs to be an actual number for that to produce the desired message.

That doesn't work with `#error`, which doesn't do macro substitutions in the text.

Here, `STRINGIFY` has the usual two-stage definition:

```
#define STRINGIFY_(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_(x)
```

You can also write the whole message inside the arguments, at least in this case, but watch out for unexpected expansions:

```
#pragma message STRINGIFY(LONG BIT is LONG_BIT)
```