# C program syntax

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

I am working on an old C code repo that has some weird syntax that I have never seen.

```
char (*__kaboom)[NUM_ELEMS( Port ) ] = NULL;
```

How does this work? what does __kaboom do and how can we use it say for example in a print statement?

And other places like these

```
char (*name)[MAX] = NULL;
name = (char (*)[MAX]) malloc(MAXB*sizeof(char));
```

I am new to C programming and appreciate your suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: Found answer for __kabbom here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979565/how-can-i-print-the-result-of-sizeof-at-compile-time-in-c/35261673#35261673
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, `NUM_ELEMS(Port)` is a macro that expands to `(sizeof(Port)/sizeof(Port[0]))` or something similar.  If so, it only works properly when the argument is the name of an array defined in the source file (not declared `extern` and defined in another file) that is not a function parameter.  Whatever it is, it must expand to an integer constant, or to nothing.

The notation:

```
char (*variable)[SIZE] = NULL;
```

is declaring a pointer to an array of the given size and type, and setting the pointer to `NULL`.

The definition and cast in the second fragment are conceptually similar.

The name `__kaboom` is reserved for the implementation to use.   Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says:

> - *All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.*
> - *All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.*

See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449181)

Comment: `It only works properly when the argument is an array that is not a function parameter` no  : https://godbolt.org/z/nYaqG8

Comment: @0: What does your link show?  I don't go to random web sites, not even godbolt.com.  What I said is a sufficiently good approximation to the truth for someone learning C, I believe.  Unless you care to spell out in a comment exactly what your complaint is.

Comment: `NUM_ELEMS(Port)` does not have to be something you think

Comment: I said "likely" — that's my judgement call.  You're right; it is also possible that I'm wrong.  I'm not sure it warrants a comment, though.

Comment: Chuckling... Yes... in the world of possibilities it could be an array of constants, a lookup table, etc... which is why this site requires [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Advise: Don't tug on Superman's cape -- rarely beneficial...)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think i find the solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979565/how-can-i-print-the-result-of-sizeof-at-compile-time-in-c/35261673#35261673

Comment: The macro can work as long as the size of the array is known at the point of use. If the array is declared with a size it is OK, and if the array is declared without a size and defined in the same file, but after the point of use, it is not OK.

Answer (score 1):

In this declaration

```
char (*__kaboom)[NUM_ELEMS( Port ) ] = NULL;
```

there is declared a pointer to an array of the type `char[NUM_ELEMS( Port ) ]`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello";
    
    char ( *p )[sizeof( s )] = NULL;
    
    p = ( char ( * )[sizeof( s )] )malloc( sizeof( char ) * sizeof( s ) );
    
    strcpy( *p, s );
    
    puts( *p ); 

    free( p );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
```

That is if you have an array like

```
char s[N];
```

then a pointer to such an array can be declared like

```
char ( *p )[N] = &s;
```

Or you can assign the address of a dynamically allocated memory for an array of the type `char[N]` (or `char [MAX]` as in your example) to the pointer

```
p = ( char ( * )[N] ) malloc( N * sizeof( char ) );
```

Dereferencing the pointer you will get the pointed array (lvalue).

Answer (score 1):

1. define `__kaboom` as pointer to array of `NUM_ELEMS( Port )` char elements and initialize it to NULL  (BTW identifiers are not allowed to start with `__`)
2. define `name` as pointer to array of `MAX` char elements and initialize it to NULL
3. Assign pointer from the point `2.`  with reference to memory allocated by the malloc function.